# making multi-dimensional nulls or ones from numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I want to create an array filled with ones or zeros based on this array

```
testArray = np.array([7,5,3])
```

so the final result should look like

```
[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1]]
```

Comment: Should your final result be a 7x7 array with zeros where you haven't designated ones? Numpy arrays cannot have jagged data as you have shown otherwise.

Comment: How do you plan on using or accessing your final array?  A list of lists might be best, but an array with filler or an object array of arrays might work better depending on your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Every row (and column, etc) in a numpy array must have the same length.  You can achieve what @ChrisWilson4 did, and fill the empty parts with `0` or `np.nan`.  Create an empty array with number of rows equal to length of `lengths`, and number of columns equal to the largest row:

```
fill = 1    # or `0` or `np.nan`
background = 0 # or `np.nan`
lengths = np.array([7,5,3])

a = np.ones((lengths.size, lengths.max()))*background
```

and fill it up with your `fill` value:

```
for row, length in enumerate(lengths):
    a[row,:length] = fill

a
#array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
#       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
#       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Or, for `fill = 0` and `background = np.nan`:

```
array([[  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  nan,  nan],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan]])
```

Or, you can make a list of lists, in the pure python way (without using numpy) like so:

```
fill = 1
lengths = [7,5,3]
a = [ [fill]*length for length in lengths ]

a
#[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: You can have numpy object arrays where each element is an array of a different size (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a ragged array of `object` dtype:

```
>>> result = np.array([np.ones(a) for a in testArray])
>>> print result
[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.] [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.] [ 1.  1.  1.]]
```

For zeros, just use `np.zeros`.

Comment: Note, you cannot index this like an ordinary array, as it is simply the `numpy` version of a list of lists, but it is an array of arrays.

Comment: Technically, you can index this array as an ordinary array (e.g. you can have a (2x2) version of the above and do slices as normal. What you can't do is to index the individual elements as part of the array. There are some advantages of an object array over a list.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call this a ragged array: it's an ordinary array, of shape `(3,)`, and behaves as such.

Comment: @DSM: by that logic, there are no ragged arrays in C either.

Comment: You're right, but the shape of interest here is `(3,<7/5/3>)` and it doesn't behave like that.  If it were "2x2" then its shape would just be `(2,2,<7/5/3>)` and you cannot access the last axis in an ordinary way.  I think we would need more information from the OP about their planned use before knowing which is better. +1 for the suggestion though :)

Comment: @tiago: that's in fact how I'd look at it, although there are [several views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967680/are-multidimensional-arrays-like-in-c-c-special-cases-of-ragged-arrays) on the matter.  What `ndarray` can't do and `list` can, and what `double x[2][3]` can't do but making an array of pointers can, seems to me well-described by "ragged".  YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

just write a quick list comprehension:

```
>>> holder = [np.ones((testArray[i])) for i in range(len(testArray))]
>>> holder
[array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]), array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]), array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.]])]
```

if you want it to be in the write format you can always reshape it:

```
>>> np.array(holder).reshape(3,1)
array([[array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])],
       [array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])],
       [array([ 1.,  1.,  1.])]], dtype=object)
```

problem solved!

Comment: wow, I didn't even notice that...it's because I am using list comprehension and generating an array inside because it returns a numpy array

Comment: I meant each array inside the list comprehension is 2d: You used `np.ones((1,testArray[i]))`, why not `np.ones(testArray[i])`?

Comment: just a force of habit because I generally only use numpy for multidimensional arrays. fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Like @JoshAdel said in comments, the int array cannot be jagged, meaning the rows can't be different lengths. Is this what you were looking for?

```
public class soArray {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] testArray = soArray.array(7,5,3);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < testArray[0].length; j++){
            System.out.print(testArray[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
public static int[][] array(int a, int b, int c){

    int max;
    if(a > b && a > c)
        max = a;
    else if(b > a && b > c)
        max = b;
    else
        max = c;
        
    int[][] out = new int[3][max];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++){
        if(i < a)
            out[0][i] = 1;
        else
            out[0][i] = 0;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i< b; i++){
        if(i < b)
            out[1][i] = 1;
        else
            out[1][i] = 0;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < c; i++){
        if(i < c)
            out[2][i] = 1;
        else
            out[2][i] = 0;
    }
    
    return out;
}
```

}

It will print out :

> 1111111
>
> 1111100
>
> 1110000

Comment: That's some very strange looking Python.  (`numpy` is a Python vector math library.)

Comment: Hahaha, I just spent like 20 minutes typing that without even reading the tags. Ohh, how I love wasting time.